# solution for an offline server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, freebsd

I'm trying to setup a development server at work that will ideally be able to test drive a couple of projects in PHP, Rails, or Django (not always running at the same time). I develop the apps locally on a Mac and then I'll put the projects up on this server for testing with my actual users (non-techies) before deploying to a production server.

My problem is that we have a very poor internet connection (almost negligible) at work and doing the usual `apt-get`/`yum`/`ports` (`make`, `clean`, `install`) processes for setting up servers always get their packages from online repositories somewhere. I know I could probably download the source and then compile them myself but that's going to be too much of a hassle for me.

I'm thinking about two solutions:

> Plan A:
>
> Run a server VM on my Mac and then use this VM as the source repository for the offline server. I've read about Ubuntu's apt-proxy and it seems to be good enough though I haven't tried it yet.

I'm not sure if this is possible but can I simply do `apt-get install nginx --downloadonly` so that the package and its dependencies will be downloaded into my VM and my server can use the VM as the source repo for apt-get?

> Plan B:
>
> Run a server VM on my Mac (which I can setup/update easily when I'm home) and then clone the VM to the offline development server. Maybe I should simply make the server a VM host so I can simply copy the VM over.

I think this is okay for the first-time setup but subsequent updates will take too long (cloning the VM image).

If I was working on Windows, I imagine it'd be easier because most services have an installer file that I can download and then run at the server.

If you could suggest another way, it would be much appreciated.

*Update:*

From Michael Hampton's answer, I found a possible solution which is `apt-cacher`.

I also found this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server) on Ubuntu's website.

I wonder if there is a better tool than this one.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [apt-mirror](http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-local-ubuntu-repository-using-apt-mirror-apt-cacher) to create a local mirror.

Comment: Apt-mirror requires 15GB for the entire repository. I don't need to mirror the entire repository. Thanks for the link though. It pointed me to apt-cacher.

Comment: What else are you doing with that 3TB drive? :)

Comment: I didn't mention anything about a 3TB drive. That server is simply a re-purposed i7 Desktop with 4GB Ram and 500GB HD. Not really an ideal server but I'll make do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into `apt-offline`([see debian-administration.org](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT)) ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm running small Ubuntu devel virtual on VMware Fusion. 4GB disk and 512MB RAM is enough for development. Network of VM is in NAT mode, so I can access it even when not on Internet. I also configured AFPd so I can edit files directly mounting share. As far as I'm doing Django only that way setup is as following... Django app running under some user account I created, that user homedir is also a `virtualenv` root (loaded on login), I use that user to login to AFP. When new project I just clone template machine and create new user account + `virtualenv`.
Installing to VMware Ubuntu chooses kernel that holds main virtualisation abilities... thus XEN, KVM, VMware. Deploymnet should then be **DevOps** way... just copying VM files to cloud and starting it online (maybe conversion of disk file or its growing to production size).

Answer (score 0):

I use apt-cacher for a private cloud and just use the defaults and it just works. I'm a big fan. You'll have to update your sources.list unless they are installed using the location of your apt-cacher.